# C++ SFML Sprite.setColor(sf::Color) Details

Tags: c++, colors, render, sfml

I'm attempting to replicate the effect of having a translucent color layer over a solid image in SFML. I have my base image which renders fine in SFML. In my image editor, I have numerous layers over the image to create various colored instances of the image. For example, the first red layer I've used has an RGBA value of 222, 14, 14, 128. When I use SFML's setColor method (using this same RGBA code) on the base image's sprite, the color of the end image is not the same, and is appearing much less vibrant. Am I misunderstanding the method's usage, or is this some bug? Is there a way I can get the same color my image editor gives me?

Answer (score 0):

SFML's setColor function uses multiplication. If you were to use a color of pure white (255,255,255) the sprite would look the same. As you're describing the color in your image editor as less "vibrant" I suspect that your layer is using a color Add, rather than a multiply.

Comment: I found the issue to be the alpha level; it sets the alpha of the actual image to 128, and does not just create a color overlay on top of the original image of this alpha value as I expected. It is therefore blending with colors behind it when it is rendered translucently.